# Countup to a specific number till the end of the day

Tags: jquery, count, counter, countdown

I need a jquery to count up to a specific number (let's say 750) till midnight.
It will use visitor's clock of course, and repeat the count up daily.

I tried several modifications but nothing worked for me.
Is there anyone who can fingure that out?

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided a single bit of code, we don't know what you've tried and I don't see a reason to provide code for it.

Here is how you would do it.

1:  Get the current time on a user's computer.
2:  Calculate the timestamp for midnight.
3:  A day is 86400 seconds long or 86400000 ms long.
4:  Find the percentage of time remaining.
5:  Multiple that percentage against the specific number you want and floor it.